# compileJava doesn't work with local libraries

Tags: java, gradle, gradle-plugin

I'm newbie with Gradle and i'm starting to apply it to an existing project.
What i would like to do is compile java classes using the compileJava task of the java plugin.
I followed the documentation to add all of the jars contained to my local directory but it doesn't seem to work.

When i run the compileJava task it continues to print messages like
"javax.servlet.http does not exist"
"javax.servlet does not exist"
etc. 
etc.

It prints messages as above for every package contained in my local folder and even if i try to print dependencies using the 'gradle dependencies' command it prints:

> annotationProcessor - Annotation processors and their dependencies for
>   source set 'main'. No dependencies
>
> apiElements - API elements for main. (n) No dependencies
>
> archives - Configuration for archive artifacts. No dependencies
>
> compile - Dependencies for source set 'main' (deprecated, use
>   'implementation ' instead). No dependencies
>
> compileClasspath - Compile classpath for source set 'main'. No
>   dependencies
>
> compileOnly - Compile only dependencies for source set 'main'. No
>   dependencies
>
> default - Configuration for default artifacts. No dependencies
>
> implementation - Implementation only dependencies for source set
>   'main'. (n) No dependencies
>
> runtime - Runtime dependencies for source set 'main' (deprecated, use
>   'runtimeOnly ' instead). No dependencies
>
> runtimeClasspath - Runtime classpath of source set 'main'. No
>   dependencies
>
> runtimeElements - Elements of runtime for main. (n) No dependencies
>
> runtimeOnly - Runtime only dependencies for source set 'main'. (n) No
>   dependencies
>
> testAnnotationProcessor - Annotation processors and their dependencies
>   for source set 'test'. No dependencies
>
> testCompile - Dependencies for source set 'test' (deprecated, use
>   'testImplementation ' instead). No dependencies
>
> testCompileClasspath - Compile classpath for source set 'test'. No
>   dependencies
>
> testCompileOnly - Compile only dependencies for source set 'test'. No
>   dependencies
>
> testImplementation - Implementation only dependencies for source set
>   'test'. (n) No dependencies
>
> testRuntime - Runtime dependencies for source set 'test' (deprecated,
>   use 'testRuntimeOnly ' instead). No dependencies
>
> testRuntimeClasspath - Runtime classpath of source set 'test'. No
>   dependencies
>
> testRuntimeOnly - Runtime only dependencies for source set 'test'. (n)
>   No dependencies

So...it can't get the dependencies properly.
I've tryied to get one dependency from a remote repository as mavencentral() or jcenter and everything works fine.

Can someone help me? Is there something that i'm making in the wrong way? It seems that fileTree is not working fine.

This is my gradle.build file:

```
plugins { 
    id 'java'
}

//Source and target compatibility.
sourceCompatibility = '1.7'
targetCompatibility = '1.7'

//Libraries local repository.
repositories {

    flatDir {
        dirs 'src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/lib'
    }

}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir:'src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/lib', include: ['*.jar'])   
}

//Source sets.
sourceSets {

    //Thes configuration under 'main' will be used for the production environment.
    main {

        java {

            //Source directory of the java files.
            srcDir 'src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/classes'

        }

        //.class files output directory
        java.outputDir = file('src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/classes')

    }

}
```

Comment: How did you install gradle?

Comment: I' ve installed it using homebrew on Mac. It was something like brew  install gradle . the version is 4.9.